# Bootstrap: Element with position fixed inside modal not aligned with respect to the viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

As far as I know, elements with `position: fixed` are aligned with respect to the viewport. But in [THIS](http://jsbin.com/qereqayeju/edit?html,css,js,output) scenario, the `fixed` element (`.box`) is positioned with respect to the modal.

Why does this happen and how can I make it align with respect to the viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because CSS `transform` propery is applied on Bootstrap's `.modal-dialog` element. As per the documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering

> Specifying a value other than none for the transform property
>   establishes a new local coordinate system at the element that it is
>   applied to. The mapping from where the element would have rendered
>   into that local coordinate system is given by the element’s
>   transformation matrix. Transformations are cumulative. That is,
>   elements establish their local coordinate system within the coordinate
>   system of their parent. From the perspective of the user, an element
>   effectively accumulates all the transform properties of its ancestors
>   as well as any local transform applied to it. The accumulation of
>   these transforms defines a current transformation matrix for the
>   element.

In other words, the containing block for a fixed-position descendant of a transformed element is the transformed element, not the viewport.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/

**Here**, if you want `.box` element to align with respect to the viewport, try placing the element outside the `.modal-dialog` element.

http://jsbin.com/wevoferuyo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: if .box needs fixed positioning, place it outside the .modal-dialog element.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed positioning works in relation to the viewport except when an ancestor element has a transform applied to it. .modal-dialog has transform applied to it which creates a new context in which to position the DIV (this is why your DIV stays inside of the modal).